# How to search FAQ?

Tags: support

So many of my questions are answered by going through the FAQs under Questions (not the FAQ you should read when you first start using AskUbuntu). There is a lot there.

How do I search that FAQ? I checked the advance search tips, but couldn't find what I was looking for. I could do it with whatever criteria determines questions become part of that FAQ, but I can't find exactly what that is either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching within the FAQ is currently not possible:

- [How can we search inside the "faq tab"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157700/how-can-we-search-inside-the-faq-tab)

It appears to be based on links:

- [How are the FAQ questions chosen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112263/how-are-the-faq-questions-chosen)

Comment: Not the answer I prefer, but the right one. I guess I could get roughly the same thing by searching for results with more than a certain amount of views. Thanks!

Comment: Consider using `views:` as a search term, most of our FAQs also happen to be high traffic, might help get you what you need.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/greatest-hits is also pure gold.